# String.Format foreach loop through string array

Tags: arrays, string, format

I want to format a string but I could have multiple values for IP addresses (2), how would I be able to loop through computer.IPaddresses array and format the string with additional values if necessary?

```
string full = string.Format("T:{0},SN:{1},IP:{2}", DateTime.UtcNow, computer.ComputerName,
                    computer.IPaddresses.FirstOrDefault());
```

If I do the above, I get only 1 address in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to loop and build your multiple IP string the try out string.join

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx